# Как проверить наличие элемента по координатам при помощи JS?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, координаты

Я пытаюсь реализовать двигающийся элемент на странице. Элемент двигается с  помощью `setInterval`, постоянно меняя свои координаты. Движение прямолинейное.

Проблема возникает, когда я пытаюсь реализовать проверку того, что находится на пути элемента. Когда двигающийся элемент не более пары пикселей в ширину и высоту, то достаточно одной/двух проверок при помощи `document.elementFromPoint(x, y)`, но когда элемент хотя бы несколько десятков пикселей в ширину и высоту, то одной такой проверки становится недостаточно. Пока нашел только один выход - делать 4 проверки, по одной на каждый угол элемента.

Есть ли какие-то более удобные способы проверить что находится в пределах каких-то координат?
Заранее спасибо за ответы.

Comment: Проверяйте расстояния между центрами объектов. Если оно меньше суммы половины ширин, то у вас имеется касание с проникновением)

Comment: Так дело в том, что объектов может быть несколько. Или даже потенциально много. Проверять на соприкосновение с каждым разве не дольше выйдет?

Comment: @BlackDrake, дольше чем что?

Comment: По идее вам и так надо со всеми проверять, так что речь идёт лишь о сокращении операций + вы можете отсортировать объекты так, чтобы проверять лишь очередной объект

Comment: @Grundy дольше, чем проверка каждого угла элемента, как я написал изначально.

Comment: @AlexanderChernin Спасибо, попробую реализовать так.

Comment: Если это что-то похожее на динозавра прыгающего через кактусы, то вам нужно расставить все кактусы по порядку, завести индекс текущего кактуса и проверять пересечение динозавра с кактусом по текущему индексу)

Comment: Это конечно похоже, но это не совсем то. Количество элементов, с которыми может быть соприкосновение довольно велико и генерируются они в случайных местах.